# Soap webservice returns "The content type application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8"

Tags: xml, web-services, wcf, soap, joomla

I'am trying to communicate with some SOAP webservice (which is from Joomla)
I keep getting this error:

```
The content type application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 330 bytes of the response were: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope
                        xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
                            <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
                                <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
                                <faultstring>401 Unauthorized</faultstring>
                            </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
                        </'.
```

I have tried every binding I can think of but I am yet to figure out what is causing my problems

Code:

```
            using (NewPconradesenTest.Tag.siteredshopbtag100Client client = new Tag.siteredshopbtag100Client())
        {
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = username;
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;
            client.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("\nClient State: " + client.State.ToString());

            try
            {
                Tag.readList_filters filter = new Tag.readList_filters();
                var result = client.readList(0, 99, emptyString, filter, emptyString, emptyString, language);

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(e.Source.ToString());
                //Console.WriteLine(e.HResult.ToString());
                //Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace.ToString());
            }
        }
```

App.config:

```
<bindings>
    <customBinding>
        <binding name="site.redshopb-tag.1.0.0">
            <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
            <httpTransport/>
        </binding>
    </customBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
    <endpoint address="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;view=tag&amp;api=soap"
        binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="site.redshopb-tag.1.0.0"
        contract="Tag.siteredshopbtag100" name="site.redshopb-tag.1.0.0_Soap" />
</client>
```

I hope somebody can help me, Thanks for your time

Comment: Any specific reason for using CustomBinding? Also please post on how your WCF service looks like and the server side config with binding details.  Is your client a .NET app?

Comment: I have tried all VS standard binding, but the reason for I am using a Custom Bindin tg ishat when I added the service reference visual studio made it automatic. I cannot post server side config fil because it is not my service, it is a webservice from a different company. The webservices is a php webservices (Joomla)

and yes my client are a .NET app

Comment: Have the web service guys provided any information on the authentication mechanism? It is more about being able to authenticate to the webservice from your client. Just try to access the webservice from SOAPUI and see if you can get a successful response back

Comment: Now he has, I send my code to him and he has responded with fixed code.
I will post my new code in a new answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up sending my code to the webservice guys, and the ended up saving me.

```
        using (webservice.client request = new webservice.client ())
        {
            using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(request.InnerChannel))
            {
                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(header);

                HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
                httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + this.Base64Encode(Program.username + ":" + Program.password));
                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;

                var result = request.readList(0, 100, null, filter, null, null, Program.language);
                this.printOutArrays(result);
            }
        }
```